# Find and replace *similar* lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, token

Initial Note:
Please mark this as duplicate, if it already exists, I didn't know how to search for it.

Have some lines in notepad that look like this:

```
Line 1: a x a x a x a
...
Line m: a y a y a y a
...
Line n: a z a z a z a
```

The "..." represent other rows with whatever content.

And what I would need to do is search for patters, where I can maintain the different part that is different.

The problem is that I can't just do "replace all instances of 'a'", because I need just SOME of the instances of 'a' to be replaced; In this case, "replace the second instance of 'a' of each relevant row"

Therefore, I would need to search for all rows that have

```
a 'variable data_1' a 'variable data_2' a 'variable data_3' a
```

And replace it with

```
a 'variable data_1' **b** 'variable data_2' a 'variable data_3' a
```

And the end result should look like this:

```
Line 1: a x b x a x a
...
Line m: a y b y a y a
...
Line n: a z b z a z a
```

What I don't know is:
How can I somehow define that "this part of the text will be variable" patterns?

If this can not be done in NPP, if you know of a software that can do it, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for :

```
((a)\s*'[^']*'\s*)\2((?:\s*'[^']*'\s*\2)+)
```

and replace by :

```
\1**b**\3
```

In the search pattern,

- `\1` is the block before the token we want to change
- `\2` is the repeated token whose second repetition we want to change
- `\3` is the block after the token we want to change

and the second iteration of the repeated token is left out of the groups because we replace it by another value in the replacement text.

Comment: Thanks, however, this one worked: ((a)\s+[^\s]+\s+)\2((?:\s+[^\s]+\s+\2)+), but only if I don't have other content in-between the rows of this scope. If I do, it only makes the change in the first occurrence. The one in the current edit doesn't work at all.